# Should I outsource my database connection in delphi?

Tags: sql, delphi

My program keeps making new requests to a database while it's running. Now, I am wondering if I should outsource my database connection, since it always creates a new one for a new query and destroys it afterwards.

```
function TMainMenu.btnInsertPersonClick(Sender: TObject)
var
   vDatabase : TADOConnection;
   vQuery : TADOQuery;
begin
   vDatabase := TADOConnection.Create(self);
   vQuery := TADOQuery.Create(self);
   try
      vDatabase.ConnectionString := 'SECRET_STRING';
      vQuery.Connection := vDatabase;

      // DO QUERY STUFF HERE

   finally
      vDatabase.Close;
      vQuery.Destroy;
      vDatabase.Destroy;
   end;
end;
```

Maybe it's not a good idea to outsource the connection. That's why I am happy about any help or suggestions. Sheers!

Comment: Opening a database connection is a relatively long process. I don't know what you mean by *outsource a database connection* but for sure it is better to let the connection always open, except when the application has not made any request for significant time. The connection could also be broken by the database server and your code should automatically reconnect when needed.

Comment: Typically the database connection is opened when the program starts and is closed when it exits.

Comment: As a side note, you should free objects by calling `Free`, not `Destroy`.

Comment: Creating connection object for every action is justified if the action is done in separate thread when responsiveness of main thread is more important than the performance of the action. btnInsertPersonClick name indicates you are not using that, so reusing a connection is a way to go. In my opinion even creating TADOQuery objects dynamically is a waist of time - you could just drag and drop them on a form or a datamodule.

Comment: Connection pooling is an alternative.

Comment: @jarlh Connection pooling is only useful in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: Another side note, your try/finally is wrong. (if `TADOQuery.Create` raise an exception, you leak a `TAdoConnection`).  You should either use nested try/finally, or initialise `vQuery` to `nil`, and create the `TADOQuery` inside the try block (This second one requires converting `destroy` to `free` first).

Comment: What does *outsource my database connection* mean? Outsourcing typically means hiring workers in another country to handle work for you, such as staffing your US-based company's support desk with lower-paid workers from an offshore nation. Since that clearly doesn't apply to a database connection, it's unclear what your intended meaning might be. You should [edit] to make it more clear.